# jQuery scrollbar in a tooltip only loading properly on window resize, content is reloading every time activated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a custom jQuery scrollbar inside of a jQuery tooltip.

***In firefox*** if you click twice to open, e.g. if it opens, then instead of closing it you activate the tooltip a second time.

***In chrome*** it only shows up and functions ok when you resize the browser window.

I tried to duplicate this in a fiddle to show, but the fiddle works fine for non-dynamic content: http://jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/JdAmG/71/ **the fiddle will still display what i'm working with**.

**HTML of the tooltip is actually using php inline:**

```
<div class="grab-this">
<div id="tip-content" class="nano">
    <div class="scrollContent">
    <?php foreach ( $member_info as $member ) : ?>
        <div class="member">
            <div class="member-photo">
                <img class="photo" src="<?php echo $member->photo_url ?>"/></div>
            <div class="team-member-screen-name">                                       
            <a href="<?php echo $member->url ?>"><?php echo $member->screen_name ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
</div>
```

**i'm grabbing that content for the tooltip using:**

```
var team = $('.grab-this').html();
```

**Activating the tooltip like:**

```
$('.tooltip').tipTip({activation: 'click', content: team, enter: function(){
    $("#tip-content.nano", "#tiptip_content").nanoScroller();
});
```

I notice in Chrome more than anything else that the images as well as the list seem to get repopulated everytime I open the tooltip. Not sure how to fix that.

Also, I actually moved the enter callback in the library to support this at all, was previously before the content was loaded into the tooltip.

**Any ideas at all would be appreciated. At this point even a hack to fake a window resize or a way to force the scrollbar to reset after the content is 100% loaded would be amazing. Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the `mCustomScrollbar` plugin. I found that because I was dynamically setting the height of the div containing the content that I was applying the scrollbar too, nothing worked (but it did when I resized the window). So, in the style sheet I set the height of the div to 1px, and I set `updateOnContentResize` to true when the plugin was initialised, as follows:

```
$( '.mCustomScrollbar' ).mCustomScrollbar ( { advanced: { updateOnContentResize: true } } );
```